# Zip Exception Wrong CRC value when opening a ZIP file - Syncfusion

Tags: syncfusion, php-ziparchive

I have a password protected zip file with 3 folders PFC, STA and SYS. The zip file when loaded for the first time reads all the text files in the PFC folder and display the data onto the screen. I perform some operations on the screeen which generates new files and they are added into the STA and SYS folders and the same initial zip file is updated.

However, when I try to load the same zip file which now should have the all the initial files and folders along with the newly created files in it, it gives me a Wrong CRC Value error. I dont know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to reproduce the issue by preparing a sample with your scenario. But, we are facing another issue related to password which we will fix in our upcoming release. The sample can be downloaded from the below link .

Sample link : https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Password-1299200154.zip

Kindly modify the sample to reproduce the “CRC value error” issue and update us along with input documents. It will help us to analyze further on this and provide you a solution at earliest.

Note : I work for Syncfusion.

You can send your sample or confidential information in mail to, support@syncfusion.com

Regards,

Mohan.